# Transforming text for a Keras CNN

Tags: python, keras

I'm trying to apply the methods of the paper 'Text Understanding from scratch' to a different dataset. I'm having difficulty getting my model to run.

I've got my sentences into a Tensor of shape

```
(19579, 140, 69)
```

And I've used the following to preprocess my targets:

```
lb = sklearn.preprocessing.LabelBinarizer()
lb.fit(authors)
targets = lb.transform(authors)
targets = targets.reshape((targets.shape[0], 1, targets.shape[1]))
```

which comes out as a

```
(19579, 1, 3)
```

Tensor

My model is:

```
nb_filter = 256
dense_outputs = 1024
cat_output = 3
batch_size = 80
nb_epoch = 10
inputs = Input(shape=(maxlen, vocab_size), name='input', dtype='float32')
conv0 = Convolution1D(nb_filter=nb_filter, filter_length=18, border_mode='valid', activation='relu', input_shape=(maxlen, vocab_size))(inputs)
conv0 = MaxPooling1D(pool_length=2)(conv0)

conv1 = Convolution1D(nb_filter=nb_filter, filter_length=14, border_mode='valid', activation='relu', input_shape=(maxlen, vocab_size))(conv0)
conv1 = MaxPooling1D(pool_length=2)(conv1)

conv2 = Convolution1D(nb_filter=nb_filter, filter_length=4, border_mode='valid', activation='relu', input_shape=(maxlen, vocab_size))(conv1)

conv3 = Convolution1D(nb_filter=nb_filter, filter_length=4, border_mode='valid', activation='relu', input_shape=(maxlen, vocab_size))(conv2)

conv4 = Convolution1D(nb_filter=nb_filter, filter_length=4, border_mode='valid', activation='relu', input_shape=(maxlen, vocab_size))(conv3)

conv5 = Convolution1D(nb_filter=nb_filter, filter_length=4, border_mode='valid', activation='relu', input_shape=(maxlen, vocab_size))(conv4)

conv6 = Convolution1D(nb_filter=nb_filter, filter_length=4, border_mode='valid', activation='relu', input_shape=(maxlen, vocab_size))(conv5)
conv6 = MaxPooling1D(pool_length=2)(conv6)

dense0 = Dropout(0.5)(Dense(dense_outputs, activation='relu')(conv6))
dense1 = Dropout(0.5)(Dense(dense_outputs, activation='relu')(dense0))

pred = Dense(cat_output, activation='softmax', name='output')(dense1)

model = Model(input=inputs, output=pred)

sgd = SGD(lr=0.01, momentum=0.9)
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=sgd, metrics=['accuracy'])
```

But when I call

```
model.fit(x=X_train, y=y_train)
```

I get the following error:

```
ValueError: Error when checking target: expected output to have shape (None, 5, 3) but got array with shape (15663, 1, 3)
```

I realise I've not preprocessed the targets correctly, but I can't figure out exactly what's going on!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The shape of the model's output (which is `(None, 5, 3)`) must be equal to the shape of your target data (which is `(None, 1, 3)`).

You entered with an input like `(None, maxlen, vocab_size)`.
Your convolutional layers and pooling layers reduced maxlen to a final value of 5. (See `model.summary()` to understand what is going on with your shapes).

You must find a way to transform this 5 into 1. There are a few possibilities.

- Add a `GlobalMaxPooling1D` or `GlobalAveragePooling1D` before the dense layer.
- `Flatten()` the data before the Dense layer.

Comment: OMG,  I rolled my eyes when I realised what I'd done wrong.